# How do I install the new Nvidia driver after purging to fix login loop?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I recently had an issue with a Nvidia update that caused a password loop. When I entered my password the screen would go dark and return to the enter password screen. I finally solved the problem with a command I found on the web:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

After rebooting, I could log in. However, I think the driver being used now is noveau. What command do I use to install the new driver from Nvidia?

Answer (score 1):

Start Software Updater from the Administration section.

1. Select the settings option.
2. Select Additional drivers.
3. Select the appropriate Nvidia driver.
4. Apply changes.